# How does conda interact with VS code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to learn python using the conda platform, I added conda to VS Code but when I run my hello world I get this.[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpyld.jpg)

The code runs but still has an error. Also, I added tensorflow to my anaconda folders, the tensor flow base and folders show up in my conda environment page, but when I import
tensorflow using `import tensorflow as tf` and check the version with `print(tf.__version__)`
 I get this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Y4c.jpg)

Comment: You need to change your integrated terminal. Conda or Python are not recognized automatically by Powershell. Use Anaconda's own terminal and you should be golden.

Comment: You should provide your error messages as code not images...its easier for us to understand that way.